# What is the difference between assertions and unparameterized predicates in Alloy?

Tags: alloy

Is there a difference between an assertion and an unparameterized predicate in Alloy? You can use the "check" command on both unparameterized predicates and assertions to find a counterexample to a given constraint. Are these two constructs essentially the same? If so, why does the language have two constructs that serve the same purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`assert` is from an earlier version of alloy, before you could `check` predicates. As of Alloy 4 that restriction on predicates has been removed and there's no reason to use `assert` statements in new specifications.